# Apache PySpark - Reading a directory without scanning the files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-storage

We have a growing data lake of logs we keep on google storage. The data is partitioned by dates (and other stuff such as env=production/staging). Imagine the path `gs://bucket/data/env=*/date=*`

We begin an app or an analysis by creating dataframes that can be queried later on for processing. The problem is that creating the DFs takes a long time even before we do actions on them. In other words the following command takes a long time because Spark seems to be scanning all the files inside (and as I mentioned, the amount of data keeps growing).

```
df = spark.read.load("gs://bucket/data/", schema=data_schema, format="json")
```

Note that we provide the schema here. Also, after the data is loaded the partitioning works well, that is, if we filter by day we do get the speed-up that we expect. We don't want to read a specific partition from the get go, we would like to have everything in one DF and read only what we need later on.

Comment: Maybe you can use `union` after loading different files in a loop.

Comment: This will still go over all the files when I load the DF, wouldn't it? I'm trying to reduce the load time.

Comment: If you must read all the files, there's no difference, you're right. I thought you needed to read certain files.